# Can I Force SwiftUI Code to Be Synchronous

Tags: json, swiftui, synchronous

I have a static computed property in a struct where I make a web service call and would like to return the result of the web service. The web service call, however, is asynchronous, and before the call gets completed, a value gets returned.

Is there any way to force this code to be synchronous? Or can you suggest any other work around to solve this problem?

Here is my code (I have not provided the model Master):

```
struct MasterControllerStruct {
    static var isMasterPopulated = false
    
    static var objMaster : Master.MasterDetails?
    static let master : Master.MasterDetails? = {
      
        if(isMasterPopulated == false)
        {
            var viewModel = ViewModel<Master>()
        
            let url = URL(string: "URL Goes Here")!
        
            let encoded = """
            {
                <JSON Parameters go here>
            }
            """
        
            let completion = {
               objMaster = viewModel.modelData?.Data
               isMasterPopulated = true
            }
        
            viewModel.getData(url: url, encoded: encoded, completion: completion)
            return viewModel.modelData?.Data

        }
    
        else {
            return objMaster
        }
    
    }()

   }

class ViewModel<T: Codable> : ObservableObject {
     @Published var modelData : T?
 
    func getData(url: URL, encoded: String, completion: (@escaping ()->()) ) {
    
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
            
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        if let data = try? encoder.encode(encoded) {
            request.httpBody = data
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data1, response, error in
        
            if let error = error {
                print("Request error: ", error)
                return
            }
        
            guard let data1 = data1 else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            
            if let data = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data1)
            {
                self.modelData = data
                completion()
                print("Success!")
            }
            else {
                print("Does not decode correctly")
            }
        }
    }.resume()
  }
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot force it to be synchronous. It's hard to say what the best workaround is in this case because it's unclear what the role of `MasterControllerStruct` is. Perhaps you're trying to use a singleton pattern? If so, making your singleton a class and retaining the value of the asynchronous call (or the view model itself) is probably a good bet.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use a singleton pattern. If I change the struct into a class, I have the same problem of the asynchronous behaviour, how would this help?

Comment: Because you can have mutable properties. You could store a reference to the view model (which isn’t really a “view” model here) or to the data returned from it. Again, hard to say without seeing how you’re trying to use this stuff. There is probably a better architectural choice, but not knowing anything about the structure of your app, it’s not possible to make an informed recommendation.